# PHP forcing a specific set of numbers

Tags: php

Im writing a script at the moment which requires the layout to be formatted into `3 numbers ( 000 )` .... When i return my SQL, the results i get could be '1', could be '100', could be '50' it could be anywhere between 0 and 999 .... How can i always get it to return as a 3 number layout.

For instance, if  the result returns 1 it need to read 001, if it returns 50 it needs to read 050 and so on.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's the [`sprintf()`](http://php.net/sprintf) function for that:

```
$formatted_decimal = sprintf('%03d', $unformatted_decimal);
# 1 -> 001, 10 -> 010, etc...
```

Just as a general tip: Don't store the formatted version unless you have highly specific reasons to do so. Formatting for output is cheap. Storing the 'raw' data is almost always a better choice, in case you change your format requirements later.

Comment: Dang ... Thats exactly what i need ... Thanks a bunch! peace

Answer (score 1):

If you are using mysql, you can use `lpad` function, like

```
select lpad(1, 3, 0);
select lpad(id, 3, 0) as padded_id from ...;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`str_pad`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php) function

**Example**

```
str_pad($number, 3, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Comment: I can't understand why somebody down-voted my answer it's working example, you can check it here: http://codepad.org/awXopkIQ

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/de791a0d-a696-439f-8f4b-58135d1bea64/view-source

Answer (score 0):

A different solution (net necessarily the best one) is using smallint(3) unsigned zerofill in the database. If your data really "represents" this format, it could be a correct solution. However, if you just want your "presentation" to be in this format, it probably isn't.

```
represent: what the data means.
presentation: how it should look to the user.
```